# How can a task with its details (eg. date, time, location) is fetched between a website and a mobile app via a server?

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, react-native

I wish you happiness, prosperity, love, and health.

What I would like to build is similar to Uber. A website sends a task with its details(eg. date, time, location) to mobile app users via a server. When accepted by one of the app users, the task is sent back to the website, displaying the details of a user(eg. name, No. plate, license no.)

HTML, CSS, JS are used for a webpage. React Native is used for a mobile app. PHP is used as a server language. Firebase is used as a server.

Step 1. On a website, a task with its details, including date, time, location, etc., is "**sent**" to a server.

Step 2. The server "**receives**" the task.

Step 3. The server "**sends**" the task to mobile app users.

Step 4. The mobile app "**receives**" the task.

Step 5. The mobile app "**displays**" the details of the task with a 'accept' button.

Step 6. One of the users "**accepts**" the task by clicking a 'accept' button.

Step 7. The app "**sends**" the acceptance of the task in a message to the server

Step 7. The server "**only receives**" the first acceptance of the task.

Step 8. The server "**sends**" the message to the website.

Step 8-1. The server "**blocks**" the acceptance of the task by any other users.

Step 8-2. The server "**sends**" a message to the other mobile users to notify the task has been taken.

Step 9. The website "**receives**" the message.

Step 10. The website "**displays**" the details of the mobile app user with an 'ok' button.

Questions.

- What codes, statements, or functions of the languages(JS, React Native, PHP, Firebase) to use in each stage to perform those in "**xxxx**"?

Ps. Without any web development background or knowledge, studying and doing it on my own is like endeavoring to break a rock with an egg... But I know that with help of kind people I can do it. It'd be very much appreciated if your help is as much in detail as you can offer.

Thank you in advance and have a happy day!!

Answer (score 1):

So here would be how to do it based on the steps you provided:

Step 1. On a website, a task with its details, including date, time, location, etc., is "sent" to a server.

This part can be done with your PHP. The task will add to a database.

Step 2. The server "receives" the task.

Step 3. The server "sends" the task to mobile app users.

This can be done with a local API. From your app, when a user signs in, it will send a POST request to a page on your website and receive the information in a format that works well for you. That information will be parsed and displayed on your app. If you're using Javascript for your app, JSON would be easiest.

Step 4. The mobile app "receives" the task.

The mobile app would parse the JSON (or however format you have) and display it on the app.

Step 5. The mobile app "displays" the details of the task with a 'accept' button.

Step 6. One of the users "accepts" the task by clicking a 'accept' button.

When the accept button is clicked, it will run a function that will send a POST request to your website, this time with information about the "driver"(or person accepting). This should have info such as driver id, location, route id, etc.

Step 7. The app "sends" the acceptance of the task in a message to the server

Your server will process this request with PHP and send a Server Sent Event to the user to confirm their product in real-time.

Step 7. The server "only receives" the first acceptance of the task.

Step 8. The server "sends" the message to the website.

Step 8-1. The server "blocks" the acceptance of the task by any other users.

This can be done when you accept the POST payload from the app. In your PHP, you can block the task for other users. Be sure though, to prevent multiple people who click at the same time for a task, that you check the database again, once a task is requested.

Step 8-2. The server "sends" a message to the other mobile users to notify the task has been taken.

This would be done by the server sent event I stated above.

Step 9. The website "receives" the message.

Step 10. The website "displays" the details of the mobile app user with an 'ok' button.